# How to implement n:m relation in Java?

Tags: java, data-structures, indexing, hashtable, hashmap

I need to implement an n:m relation in Java.
The use case is a catalog.

- a product can be in multiple categories
- a category can hold multiple products

My current solution is to have a mapping class that has two hashmaps.

- The key of the first hashmap is the product id and the value is a list of category ids
- The key to the second hashmap is the category id and the value is a list of product ids

This is totally redundant an I need a setting class that always takes care that the data is stored/deleted in both hashmaps.

But this is the only way I found to make the following performant in *O(1)*:

- what products holds a category?
- what categories is a product in?

I want to avoid full array scans or something like that in every way.

But there must be another, more elegant solution where I don't need to index the data twice.

Please en-light me. I have only plain Java, no database or SQLite or something available. I also don't really want to implement a btree structure if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you associate Categories with Products via a member collection, and vica versa, then you can accomplish the same thing:

```
public class Product {
     private Set<Category> categories = new HashSet<Category>();
     //implement hashCode and equals, potentially by id for extra performance
}

public class Category {
     private Set<Product> contents = new HashSet<Product>();
     //implement hashCode and equals, potentially by id for extra performance
}
```

The only difficult part is populating such a structure, where some intermediate maps might be needed.

But the approach of using auxiliary hashmaps/trees for indexing is not a bad one.  After all, most indices placed on databases for example are auxiliary data structures: they coexist with the table of rows; the rows aren't necessarily organized in the structure of the index itself.

Using an external structure like this empowers you to keep optimizations and data separate from each other; that's not a bad thing.  Especially if tomorrow you want to add O(1) look-ups for Products given a Vendor, e.g.

<strike>**Edit:** By the way, it looks like what you want is an implementation of a [Multimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) optimized to do reverse lookups in O(1) as well.  I don't think Guava has something to do that, but you could implement the Multimap interface so at least you don't have to deal with maintaining the HashMaps separately.</strike>  Actually it's more like a BiMap that is also a Multimap which is contradictory given their definitions.  I agree with MStodd that you probably want to roll your own layer of abstraction to encapsulate the two maps.

Answer (score 3):

Your solution is perfectly good.  Remember that putting an object into a HashMap doesn't make a copy of the Object, it just stores a reference to it, so the cost in time and memory is quite small.

Comment: thanks i will actually stay with my implementation then but will accept the other answer because it fits better to the question of a more "elegant" solution whatever elegant is...

Answer (score 1):

I would go with your first solution.  Have a layer of abstraction around two hashmaps.  If you're worried about concurrency, implement appropriate locking for CRUD.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to use an immutable data structure, Guava's `ImmutableMultimap` offers an `inverse()` method, which enables you to get a collection of keys by value.